# AttributeError with pip install matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I am attempting to install matplotlib with pip inside a virtualenv on Ubuntu Linux.  I already have a bunch of packages installed successfully - this is the one that's failing.  As the output indicates, This is python 2.7.3 and all of the dependencies are already present.

Is this specific to v1.4.3 of matplotlib?  Should I perhaps install an earlier version?  I've even manually installed mock (v1.3.0), since the install seems to fail on trying to import it, but that didn't help either.

Here is the output:
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-1.4.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ============================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

```
BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
            matplotlib: yes [1.4.3]
                python: yes [2.7.3 (default, Jun 22 2015, 19:33:41)  [GCC
                        4.6.3]]
              platform: yes [linux2]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                 numpy: yes [version 1.9.2]
                   six: yes [using six version 1.9.0]
              dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 2.4.2]
                  pytz: yes [using pytz version 2015.4]
               tornado: yes [tornado was not found. It is required for the
                        WebAgg backend. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
             pyparsing: yes [using pyparsing version 2.0.3]
                 pycxx: yes [Couldn't import.  Using local copy.]
                libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]
              freetype: yes [version 2.4.8]
                   png: yes [version 1.2.46]
                 qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'qhull' could not be
                        found. Using local copy.]

OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
           sample_data: yes [installing]
              toolkits: yes [installing]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-mHyI6G/matplotlib/setup.py", line 155, in <module>
    result = package.check()
  File "setupext.py", line 666, in check
    import mock
  File "/home/awarnock/PyProjects/OMTO3dIMG/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    import mock.mock as _mock
  File "/home/awarnock/PyProjects/OMTO3dIMG/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 71, in <module>
    _v = VersionInfo('mock').semantic_version()
AttributeError: 'VersionInfo' object has no attribute 'semantic_version'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip- build-mHyI6G/matplotlib
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: No more calls, please.  I think I have the answer.  It appears that _uninstalling_ mock first will work.  The following succeeded:

    pip uninstall mock
    pip install --no-deps --ignore-installed matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
pip install oslo.utils
```

Or:

```
pip install testrepository
pip install oslo.utils
```

You can also install it with packages:

Debian / Ubuntu:

`apt-get install python-matplotlib`

Redhat / CentOS:

`yum install python-matplotlib`